# Automatic ip, name and dns configurations for virtual servers on demand

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, virtualization, dhcp, hostname

Current environment is several Linux boxes in a couple of logically separated "datacenters" running virtual guests that are created and deleted on demand.
DNS and DHCP run in another box and should serve all the virtual servers.

What I want is to create and remove virtual instances on demand without touching DNS and DHCP server configurations, I've certain freedom to prepare the guests but I'd like to avoid consulting central servers on guest creation.

So, ideally I would like just to create a guest with a hostname "node5.dc1.mydomain.com" and start it, it'd get ip from "mydomain.com" dhcp and register at "mydomain.com" DNS.  So that I can just create the instance and ssh into it.

I believe some combination of DHCP and DDNS could work, but I want to ensure that there aren't easier alternatives or confirm that DHCP and DDNS is the way to go.

Although i've read some bad stuff about Dynamic DNS..

Answer (score 1):

you can use some mac table for guest machines and register them with dhcpd/ddns . and write this mac to yours virtual interface in guest vm.

Comment: But that would require changing stuff in dhcp/dns servers each time I add or remove a machine, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: then you shoud try to use single DB for that. check for viper project

Comment: could you elaborate on that? I can't find anything googling for viper project

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez http://www.spinlocksolutions.com/viper/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Avahi/Bonjour for automatic [Multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org/)?

Comment: Looks like it could do the job, but being serverless doesn't look like is going to scale too good nor through different subnets.